# How to use display:table for to diplay map within a list

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I have a VO object which contains string + a map property. This object is forming a list and then I am trying to use display:table to display this list. For all string properties display:column is fine but for the map code using display:column is becoming difficult as the key of the map forms the header which has to be displayed only once as the title of the last display:column and the values will have to iterate. I saw two options of either using display:table within display:column or iterate the map. But with display:table within column I could see the title as static (which is not in my case).

The code without display:table

```
<table id="prepaid" width="1120px" style="margin-left: 20px; border: 1px solid #7591AC;" cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=0 class=tabular>

            <logic:present name="provisioningStatisticsResultList">
                 <logic:iterate id="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" name="provisioningStatisticsResultList" indexId="index">                    
                    <bean:define id="mapEntry" name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="rangeMap" />
                    <tr>
                    <logic:equal name="index"  value="0">
                         <th><bean:message key="label.applicationId" bundle="labels" /></th>
                         <th><bean:message key="label.version" bundle="labels" /></th>  
                         <th><bean:message key="label.results" bundle="labels" /></th>  

                         <logic:iterate id="map" name="mapEntry">
                            <th><bean:write name="map" property="key" /></th>
                         </logic:iterate>
                    </logic:equal>
                     </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRowEven">

                        <td class="td.iconCell"><bean:write name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="applicationId" /></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="apkVersion" /></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="activationType" /></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="status" /></td>
                        <logic:iterate id="map" name="mapEntry">
                            <td><bean:write name="map" property="value" /></td>
                        </logic:iterate>

                    </tr>
                 </logic:iterate>
            </logic:present>
</table>
```

With display:table I tried various options but nothing works, may be some syntatical error or another solution all together (commented one):

```
                     <display:table name="sessionScope.provisioningStatisticsResultList"
                        id="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="ascending"
                        pagesize="<%= recordsPerPage %>" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                        requestURI="/provisioningStatistics.do" export="true"
                        class="data_table width_full" style="margin-left:20px;">

                        <display:column title="Application ID">
                        <bean:write name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="applicationId"/>
                        </display:column>
                        <display:column title="Version">
                        <bean:write name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="apkVersion"/>
                        </display:column>
                        <display:column title="Results">
                        <bean:write name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="status"/>
                        </display:column>
                        <bean:define id="mapEntry" name="provisioningStatisticsResultListObj" property="rangeMap" />
                        <logic:iterate id="map" name="mapEntry">
                            <display:column title="<bean:write name="map" property="key" />">
                            <bean:write name="map" property="value" /></display:column>
                         </logic:iterate>
                        <%-- <display:column property="rangeMap">
                        <display:table id="mapEntry" name="rangeMap" style="margin-left:20px;">
                           <display:column title = "<bean:write name="map" property="key" />" >
                        <bean:write name="map" property="value" />
                        </display:column>
                           </display:table>
                        </display:column> --%>


                        <%-- <logic:iterate id="map" name="mapEntry" property="rangeMap" indexId="index1"> 
                        <display:column title = "<bean:write name="map" property="key" />" >
                        <bean:write name="map" property="value" />
                        </display:column>
                    </logic:iterate> --%>
                    </display:table>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>

             </logic:present>
```

My project using struts 1. Please help me correct the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the tag library that has the `display` tag defined:

`<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>`

Also, make sure the jar file [displayTag.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/displaytag/displaytag/1.2) is in your classpath.